# how get swf file size in smarty?

Tags: smarty

i have swf file:
www.link.com/file.swf

How get height and width?

Thanks

Comment: #1 - An SWF isn't an image. 2# - You want the dimensions, the size could refer to it's file size.

Comment: Yes, I need swf file dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get SWF width and height with [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) in PHP, then you need to pass this info to Smarty.